# What does it mean to integrate over something?

Tags: integration

I have a formula and I have a set of values for the volume of a sphere. I was told to take the integral over the volume and I'm not sure of what it meant.
Is it possible to explain this in layman's terms?

Edit: So, I read this formula to model a dark matter halo ρ(r) = ρ0/(1+(r/rc)^2), and this gives us the density profile for the dark matter halo. I was able to find the volume for the halo at different radii by using the formula 4*pi*r^3. Also, I was told that by integrating the first formula I have written, over the volume, I would get the mass. I wasn't able to understand why I would need to do that and hence, the question.

Thanks once again!

Comment: The more detail you give, the better. If you could reproduce the problem exactly, that would be best! (Math.SE doesn't take kindly to screenshots, fair warning)

Comment: Find the value of your function on each point on the sphere and add them up.

Comment: To give a physical intuition: suppose you knew the density at each point on your sphere. Integrating will give you the mass.

Comment: You break the volume of the sphere into several chunks, and add up the value of the function at those chunks times the volume of the chunk. As the size of the chunks goes to zero, and the number of them goes to infinity, you get an integral.

Comment: I've added an edit. Thanks so much for the answers!

Comment: "Something" (as in the title) typically would refer to an interval, region, or space: some subset of a larger set. One can then *integrate over* that object. For example, $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is the integral of $f(x)$ *over* the entire real line. So "integrating over a volume" could mean integrating a function over some subset of $\mathbb R^3$, for instance.